# В iframe не работают JS и JQ

Tags: jquery, javascript, iframe

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: у меня не работает Javascript и jquery в iframe. Я подключил библиотеку, но все равно не хочет работать. Как исправить?

**Обновление**

Я создал страницу, написал её в iframe, но в iframe не работают скрипты. Пробую открывать саму страницу, там все работают, а в iframe нет.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: в созданном с помошью js iframe ? присвойте его window jQuery

Comment: Я создал страницу, написал её в iframe, но в iframe не работают скрипты. Пробую открывать саму страницу, там все работают, а в iframe нет

Comment: в консоль что нибудь пишет ? noscript не стоит какой-нибудь ? страница локальная или на http сервере ?

Comment: страница не на сервере, она расположена на локалке. Нечего не пишет, просто не работает

Comment: в смысле url страницы file:// ?

Comment: скрипты в студию

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы открываете во фрейме страницу с другого домена, в таком случае ничего работать и не будет, это ограничение безопасности.

Comment: Странное предположение... не правда даже, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9ysvj/

Comment: страница не на сервере, она расположена на локалке. Нечего не пишет, просто не работает